# nable to download JSON metadata: HTTP Error 404: Not Found (caused by HTTPError()); please report this issue on https://yt-dl.org/bug

Tags: youtube, youtube-dl

I am trying to download the pluralsight videos using `youtube-dl`, but seems not working well and giving the below error. I have a paid pluralsight account.

How can we solve this issue ?

I have taken a reference from: **https://gist.github.com/jesperorb/c14aef85735c54f479896cfa6f16a1e5**

The error below for reference:-

```
C:\Users\pc\Downloads\youtube-dl-master\bin>youtube-dl -v --username "XXX@gmail.com" --password "XXX@123" --verbose --sleep-interval 120 "https://app.pluralsight.com/player?course=oauth2-json-web-tokens-openid-connect-introduction&author=dominick-baier&name=oauthintro-m1-overview&clip=0&mode=live"
[debug] System config: []
[debug] User config: []
[debug] Custom config: []
[debug] Command-line args: ['-v', '--username', 'PRIVATE', '--password', 'PRIVATE', '--verbose', '--sleep-interval', '120', 'https://app.pluralsight.com/player?course=oauth2-json-web-tokens-openid-connect-introduction&author=dominick-baier&name=oauthintro-m1-overview&clip=0&mode=live']
[debug] Encodings: locale cp1252, fs mbcs, out cp437, pref cp1252
[debug] youtube-dl version 2018.06.19
[debug] Python version 3.4.4 (CPython) - Windows-10-10.0.17134
[debug] exe versions: none
[debug] Proxy map: {}
[pluralsight] Downloading login page
[pluralsight] Logging in
[pluralsight] oauthintro-m1-overview-0: Downloading course JSON
[pluralsight] oauthintro-m1-overview-0: Downloading JSON metadata
ERROR: Unable to download JSON metadata: HTTP Error 404: Not Found (caused by HTTPError()); please report this issue on https://yt-dl.org/bug . Make sure you are using the latest version; type  youtube-dl -U  to update. Be sure to call youtube-dl with the --verbose flag and include its complete output.
  File "C:\Users\dst\AppData\Roaming\Build archive\youtube-dl\rg3\tmp3niajf93\build\youtube_dl\extractor\common.py", line 598, in _request_webpage
  File "C:\Users\dst\AppData\Roaming\Build archive\youtube-dl\rg3\tmp3niajf93\build\youtube_dl\YoutubeDL.py", line 2211, in urlopen
  File "C:\Python\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 470, in open
  File "C:\Python\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 580, in http_response
  File "C:\Python\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 508, in error
  File "C:\Python\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 442, in _call_chain
  File "C:\Python\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 588, in http_error_default
```

Comment: You should report the issue at https://yt-dl.org/bug .

Comment: @phihag 2 - Hey I got the solution. I am using windows. I simply did the c:/>youtube-dl -U, it downloaded latest and then its working fine now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue. I was not using the latest youtube-dl DLL and so i did the following -

> youtube-dl -U

then simply execute the command, its started downloading like below

[image]